# Вызов callback с ответом в node-redis происходит не в той точке

Tags: node-redis, node.js, redis

Пишу вебсокет сервер на nodejs, использую redis, в частности одноимённую либу. Так вот, когда извлекаю ответ, выполнение скрипта проходит дальше, не дожидаясь вызова колбэка с результатом. В браузере я мог бы применить $.Deferred. А что делать в nodejs?

Вот пример кода для наглядности:

```
console.log("STEP 1");
    // проверка сессии на существование
    rc.exists("session:" + sid, function(err, res) {
        if (!res) {
            console.log((new Date()) + " Session not exists in db");
            request.reject(401, "Authentication required");
        }

        console.log("STEP 2");
    });

console.log("STEP 3");
```

Так вот вызов STEP 2 идёт последним, а нужно сделать по порядку.

Comment: [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Comment: @Yura_Ivanov ну а можно подкрепить комент куском кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) слишком много разных методов, по приведенному вопросе коду сложно выбрать что-то конкретное. может это series, может waterfall или parallel. Посмотрите описание. Один из вариантов:

```
async.series([
  function(cb){
    console.log('1');
    cb(null,1);// первый параметр - ошибка, если не null, то серия прервется
  },
  function(cb){
    rc.exists("session:" + sid, function(err,res){
      console.log('2');
      cb(err,res);
    });
  },
  function(cb){
    console.log('3');
    cb(null,3);
  }],

  // эта функция будет вызвана, когда выполнение серий закончится
  function(err, results){
    // анализ ошибки, возникшей на каком-либо этапе
    if (err) ...

    console.log(results);// здесь будет массив из возвращенных значений 
                         // в каждом из коллбэков (второй параметр cb)
  }
);
```